# Postgres suddenly says that "Relation does not exists" (it exists for sure)

Tags: postgresql

I have a weird problem with Postgres on production server (DigitalOcean).

Suddenly, my Django project started raising this error. I've not changed anything on server for 2 months so it is not caused by any code changes etc.

```
relation "mainapp_price" does not exist
LINE 1: ...rom_3", "mainapp_price"."stelinka_12kg_pack" FROM "mainapp_p...
```

I've checked `/var/log/postgres/...` which says something similar:

```
2019-04-27 13:40:26 UTC [13288-11] postgres@brennholzdb ERROR:  relation "mainapp_availability" does not exist at character 179
2019-04-27 13:40:26 UTC [13288-12] postgres@brennholzdb STATEMENT:  SELECT "mainapp_availability"."id", "mainapp_availability"."dry_wood", "mainapp_availability"."wet_wood", "mainapp_availability"."briquettes", "mainapp_availability"."area" FROM "mainapp_availability" WHERE "mainapp_availability"."area" = 'ar' LIMIT 21
```

I don't have a clue where is the problem. As I said everything is migrated and there are no new changes in the code.

Do you know what to do?

**EDIT**

`postgres` process eats almost 100% CPU..

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                     
13277 postgres  20   0  385212   4916   2740 S 98.0  1.0 352:44.85 postgres                                                                                                                                                                                    
14096 django    20   0   40388   3524   2996 R  0.3  0.7   0:00.02 top                                                                                                                                                                                         
    1 root      20   0  119992   5124   2996 S  0.0  1.0   0:03.54 systemd                                                                                                                                                                                     
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                                                                                                                    
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.45 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                                                                                 
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H                                                                                                                                                                                
    6 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.25 kworker/u2:0                                                                                                                                                                                
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:03.56 rcu_sched
```

Comment: What is the output of `\d+`? (from within psql)

Comment: Complete Guess: Look to see if default schema changed and it is looking in wrong schema.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name @ Michael Potter I've found very suspicious log entries, it seems to be an attack so I've created a new question if you are interested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55881808/postgres-db-hacked-what-to-check-secure-in-future